# (Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V error in java for DLL

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jni4net

I am trying to run a C# code in Java with the help of Jni4Net library but I am getting an error whenever I try to create an object of the proxy class.

Code:

```
public class JNI_Snow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.load("D:/JNI_Test/In.SnowConnectorLib.j4n.dll"); 
            Bridge.setVerbose(true);
            Bridge.init();

            File proxytest= new File("In.SnowConnectorLib.j4n.dll");
            Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(proxytest);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        in.snowconnectorlib.SnowConnector test= new in.snowconnectorlib.SnowConnector();
    }}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: in.snowconnectorlib.SnowConnector.__ctorSnowConnector0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V
    at in.snowconnectorlib.SnowConnector.__ctorSnowConnector0(Native Method)
    at in.snowconnectorlib.SnowConnector.<init>(SnowConnector.java:25)
    at snowsample.JNI_Snow.main(JNI_Snow.java:27)
```

I have ensured that all the DLL and JARs are in the same work location. However it is able to load both the JNI DLL (core and custom).

It only gives an exception while creating an object of the class used in proxy DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this exact issue.

If you look at the implementation of Bridge.init(), it searches the **source** directory of "jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar" to find and load "jni4net.n.[your_platform].dll".

For some reason, your "In.SnowConnectorLib.j4n.dll" that is passed into  Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom() must be in the same directory as the loaded "jni4net.n.[your_platform].dll". I'm guessing that your "In.SnowConnectorLib.j4n.dll" is in the **output** directory, but "jni4net.n.[your_platform].dll" is loaded from your **source** directory.

I solved this by passing in the output directory (as a File) into Bridge.init(), so that it searches and loads from that directory instead of the source directory.